# How to calculate the difference of rasters within the limits where the pixel coordinates are the same?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis

I'm writing my raster calculator like Qgis.I'm stuck in one place.
I feed two images to the input, after which I find the boundary of the intersection of the coordinates of the pixels, since my two images differ in coordinates[image]

```
F=[]
F.append(r'C:\Users\user2\Desktop\1\rastrcalc\pyopencl\2012_2.tif')
F.append(r'C:\Users\user2\Desktop\1\rastrcalc\pyopencl\2011_cut_2.tif')
# For Image Processing

from math import *
import numpy
from osgeo import gdalnumeric
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdal_array import *
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import pyopencl as cl
# Set our output file format driver

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff')
# Set our output files Projection parameters
# from input file number 1

tmp = gdal.Open(F[0])
geoT = tmp.GetGeoTransform()
r1 = [geoT[0], geoT[3], geoT[0] + (geoT[1] * tmp.RasterXSize), geoT[3] + (geoT[5] * tmp.RasterYSize)]
proJ = tmp.GetProjection()

tmp2 = gdal.Open(F[1])
geoT2 = tmp2.GetGeoTransform()
r2 = [geoT2[0], geoT2[3], geoT2[0] + (geoT2[1] * tmp2.RasterXSize), geoT2[3] + (geoT2[5] * tmp2.RasterYSize)]
proJ2 = tmp2.GetProjection()
intersection = [max(r1[0], r2[0]), min(r1[1], r2[1]), min(r1[2], r2[2]), max(r1[3], r2[3])]
>>> print intersection
[286209.3065796, 5180967.071686, 286223.8630979998, 5180947.93927]
b3 = LoadFile(F[0]).astype(numpy.float32)
b4 = LoadFile(F[1]).astype(numpy.float32)

#Reshape the data from 2-D to 1-D

b3r = b3.reshape(b3.shape[0]*b3.shape[1])
b4r = b4.reshape(b4.shape[0]*b4.shape[1])
```

With the help of variable "intersection" created a frame
[image]

[image]

Now the question is how to calculate the difference of rasters exactly within the "intersection"
At the location where the pixel coordinates are the same

The principle of the raster calculator Qgis

[It is worth noting that finding the frame is taken from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/how-to-add-different-sized-rasters-in-gdal-so-the-result-is-only-in-the-intersec)

Comment: Even if the resolution of the two rasters are the same, at least one of the rasters must be resampled to have the same pixel positions. You had better to add a parameter to your program, the target resolution. gdal_translate can resample and cut rasters. After setting the pixel sizes and positions the same on the common part of the two rasters, you can make any operation pixel by pixel.

Comment: No does not fit, because I want to make a bitmap calculator faster in time than counts Qgis.i need an idea how to run the code so that it counts exactly what is in the box

Comment: Try GRASS without GUI, it has Python interface. It will be difficult to write faster code for general cases. If you'll be successful share us your code!