# GDAL (Python) open/load raster with offsets

Tags: python, gdal

I am using the Python GDAL API to perform operations on geotiffs.  I have a good understanding of what needs to be done, but the how and particularly interpreting GDAL's documentation is a barrier.  Basically I have two geotiff arrays with different extents but they overlap ~ 85%.  I just want to load each image as a numpy array in Python clipped to their common extent.

I have used this great code from another post ([How to add different sized rasters in GDAL so the result is only in the intersected region](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/how-to-add-different-sized-rasters-in-gdal-so-the-result-is-only-in-the-intersec)) but I am hung up on the arguments for `band.ReadRaster()` at the end of the accepted answer.

I can find the offset number in pixels (hypothetical example) - `xoff1 = 20, yoff1 = 100, xoff2 = 1800, yoff2 = 2000` if hypothetical `tiff1 size = 2000 x 2250`. So for an equivalent numpy array I would clip it like this: `np_array[20:1800,100:200]`

With two datasets loaded as `ds<1 and 2> = gdal.Open(filepath/to/tiff)` and all the metadata, methods, objects, etc. HOW do I finally use my extents to open clipped bands?  I want to use `band.ReadRaster()` I just don't understand the arguments.

Here is example from API tutorial of using the method: `scanline = band.ReadRaster(xoff=0, yoff=0, xsize=band.XSize, ysize=1,buf_xsize=band.XSize,buf_ysize=1, buf_type=gdal.GDT_Float32`.  And I have referenced the gdal documentation which looks the same as this example.  **I have TWO offsets per northing/easting why only one value for offset?**  I am confused.

Comment: Subtract your offsets to get `xsize` and `ysize` instead

Comment: Thanks Mike - still getting skunked.  I got the `xsize` and `ysize` but my datatype when I run: `ds.ReadRaster(20, 100, 1780, 100, 1780, 100, buf_type = gdal.GDT_Float32)` fails with `TypeError: Image data of dtype |S1415308876 cannot be converted to float`.  When I remove type arg bytes are returned.  I've also called `ReadRaster()` on `band.ReadRaster()` instead from `band = ds.GetRasterBand()` and same issue.  I am really confused on these args, data type, etc.  Not sure diff between `x_buff` and `xsize`.  Note those args displayed are the diff betw offsets as you instructed. Ideas?

Comment: You probably actually want [`band.ReadAsArray()`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html#ReadAsArray).  I believe you can simply omit all of the "buff" arguments, you would use those if you wanted to read the data into an existing buffer/array instead of returning a new one.  However if you're frustrated by the crappy auto-generated documentation I recommend learning [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead, it wraps gdal into something that behaves like a proper Python library

Comment: Grateful (Dead or did I spell that wrong?) for GDAL but I have always struggled to find documentation.  Perhaps I need to attend a conference/tutorial.  Thanks for the help!  I think that did it.  So ANSWER is as follows: 1) get offsets: [xoff from west, how many cells in from there (xsize), yoff from north, how many cells down (ysize)] 2) call `ds.ReadAsArray(x_off, xsize, y_off, ysize)` for example `ds.ReadAsArray(100, 50, 2000, 1000)`.  This will subset original raster into numpy array (*note np symbology*) as such: `original_array[100:2100, 50,1050]`.

Comment: @NW_Photo_Laureate I found [Chris Garrard's Geoprocessing with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/geoprocessing-with-python) a great introduction to GDAL.